# Add "Are you sure?" to my excel button, how can I?

Tags: vba, excel, dialog

I have a button on my form that clears the entire 8 sheet workbook. I do want to clear it occasionally, but I would hate to do it by accident. I've tried googling it, but every result I've found assumes I have a much firmer grasp of VBA than I do. How can I make it so when the button is clicked a Dialog box pops up saying "This will erase everything! Are you sure? [Continue] [Cancel]"?
Thanks.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

On your existing button code, simply insert this line before the procedure:

```
If MsgBox("This will erase everything! Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
```

This will force it to quit if the user presses no.

Comment: +1 Agree with @brettdj. Its generally better to use the constants for readability and maintainability.

Comment: +1 I like this answer, but strictly speaking, `If MsgBox("This will erase everything, are you sure?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then` would have been closer since he asked for `Continue` and `Cancel` buttons.

Comment: @JP. - I am very glad about your comment since I think OK/Cancel is more appropriate, but you've got the If/Then logic backwards...it should be `... = vbCancel Then...`. Still, +1 because a little If/Then logic isn't beyond me. (:

Comment: True, it is more in keeping with the original question, but "Are you sure?" calls Yes/No to me rather than Cancel.

Answer (score 8):

Create a new sub with the following code and assign it to your button.  Change the "DeleteProcess" to the name of your code to do the deletion.  This will pop up a box with OK or Cancel and will call your delete sub if you hit ok and not if you hit cancel.

```
Sub AreYouSure()

Dim Sure As Integer

Sure = MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbOKCancel)
If Sure = 1 Then Call DeleteProcess

End Sub
```

Jesse

Answer (score 0):

Just make a custom userform that is shown when the "delete" button is pressed, then link the continue button to the actual code that does the deleting.  Make the cancel button hide the userform.